# Why menu item going down when i shrink the window?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, bridge

i use bridge theme for my website, i do not know why but the nav menu item **"CONTATTI"** going down when i shrink the window of chrome. Have you an idea? Thank you for the attention!

http://www.cantatorearredamenti.it/ this the web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove a `Position : absolute` and make it relative.I am not that much knowledge in css but I hope this will be helpful.

```
nav.main_menu {
    position: relative;
    left: 84%;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: left;
}
```